# Format a text to currency whiles i type C#

Tags: c#

This what i have done and it works but it does not allow you to enter values with decimal point

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtsearch.Text))
{
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
      Decimal valueBefore = Decimal.Parse(txtsearch.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);
      txtsearch.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0:N0}", valueBefore);
      txtsearch.Select(txtsearch.Text.Length, 0);
}
```

Comment: If you want to format as currency use `C` and a number to represent how many decimal places you want, for sample: `txtsearch.Text = valueBefore.ToString("C2");`. It will put the symbol of your current culture.

Comment: Use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

Comment: @FelipeOriani Be aware that not all currencies use 2 decimals. There are some with 3 and even without any.

Comment: You are probably doing it inside `TextChanged` event handler. A bad idea. This will interfere with user input. Either use a dedicated masked control or perform conversion at the end of input (e.g. on enter key press).